# .NET Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I "Enable/Disable Roles" or "Create or Manage Roles" without ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool?  I am able to create user/manage user/enable user etc for my MVC3 web application using this tool.  However, I would like to give this tool to the Admins to "Create/Manage roles" and they do not have Visual Studio installed on their workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have easy access to the Roles from inside your controllers:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Guest"))
   Roles.CreateRole("Guest");

Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "Guest");
```

So if you just create a Controller and a couple of Action+View's then you can make your own tool.

And of course you will want to restrict access:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
public class RolesController : Controller
{
}
```

Comment: @rk1962 would you please care to share code as to how to made your own role manager tool? I can user this answer in my seed method but i am worried what would happen once this code is shipped to production.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create your own administration tool that uses the ASP.NET membership provider.

Alternatively, the open source project at http://websitemanager.codeplex.com/ may be useful.

Comment: I will try to create my own administration page as recommended by Henk.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am dealing with editing users and roles.

In my controller I have the following code. Don't mind the partners IList you will not need it. You will want to model up a user in your AccountController (assuming you are using this for your user accounts) with the roles.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string UserName)
{
    IList<Partner> partners = r.ListPartners();
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
    UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
    User model = new User();
    model.UserName = user.UserName;
    model.Email = user.Email;
    model.ActiveAccount = user.IsApproved;
    model.PartnerID = profile.PartnerID;
    model.IsAdministrator = Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Administrator");
    model.IsApprover = Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Approver");
    model.IsContributor = Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Contributor");
    model.IsReporter = Roles.IsUserInRole(user.UserName, "Reporter");
    IList<Partner> p = r.ListPartners();
    ViewBag.Partners = new SelectList(p.AsEnumerable(), "PartnerID", "Name", model.PartnerID);            
    return View(model);
}
```

My post looks like

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User model)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetProfile(model.UserName);
        user.Email = model.Email;
        user.IsApproved = model.ActiveAccount;            
        profile.PartnerID = model.PartnerID;           

        #region If Else Block for Role 
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Administrator") && !model.IsAdministrator)
        {
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, "Administrator");
        }
        else if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName,"Administrator") && model.IsAdministrator)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Administrator");
        }
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Reporter") && !model.IsReporter)
        {
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, "Reporter");
        }
        else if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Reporter") && model.IsReporter)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Reporter");
        }
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Contributor") && !model.IsContributor)
        {
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, "Contributor");
        }
        else if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Contributor") && model.IsContributor)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Contributor");
        }
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Approver") && !model.IsApprover)
        {
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(model.UserName, "Approver");
        }
        else if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Approver") && model.IsApprover)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Approver");
        }
        #endregion            
        Membership.UpdateUser(user);
        return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers", "Account"); 
    }
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what you need to do. I am assuming you can create a view ok with your user model.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should "educate" them on how to edit the website configuration file. Just editing roles isn't such a big deal even if they're editing XML directly